# PHP detect when class is called

Tags: php

I want to create the class once. However, I want the $contents array to be reset when the class method is called on the variables.

I can do this by recreating the class each time, but is there a different solution? How can I trigger if the class is called in any way (method etc.).

```php
<?php

class Page
{
    public $contents = array();
    
    
    public function add_content($content)
    {
       array_push($this->contents,$content);
       return $this;
    }
}

$page = new Page();

$ex = $page->add_content('example');
$ex2 = $page->add_content('example2');

?>
```

**OUTPUT**

```php
print_r($ex);
print_r($ex2);

Page Object
(
    [contents] => Array
        (
            [0] => example
            [1] => example2
        )

)
Page Object
(
    [contents] => Array
        (
            [0] => example
            [1] => example2
        )

)
```

**What i want to do**

```php
print_r($ex);
print_r($ex2);

Page Object
(
    [contents] => Array
        (
            [0] => example
        )

)
Page Object
(
    [contents] => Array
        (
            [0] => example2
        )

)
```

Comment: Hello @Riga, just create another object and call the method again like this, 
**
$page = new Page();
$page2 = new Page();

$ex = $page->add_content('example');
$ex2 = $page2->add_content('example2');
**

Comment: @AwatITWork I already know this, I mentioned it in my question. I don't want to create it by typing new every time I have to write a lot of code. Can I reset the variable with a function if I can detect that the class has been called in any way?

Comment: so you are trying to reset the array each time you add a new item **, or** you want that to happen only when a new instance is created? not quite clear.

Comment: @AwatITWork I want to reset the $contents variable if the method is called on a different variable. I didn't know if the __call magic method would work for me?

Comment: I think there's probably [an X/Y Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) here. As shown, your example makes no sense - if every method call resets the array, how would the array ever have more than one item in it? Maybe you actually want a "factory" method, that creates a new object in a given state? Or a way to create a _similar_ object, copying some properties, but resetting others? Step back and try to re-frame your question in terms of the goal you're trying to achieve, not the implementation you've thought of.

Comment: @IMSoP I may have misunderstood. My goal is to reset the contents array if the method is called on any "different" variable, instead of using new() constantly. You can think of it like a pdo class. Of course the array will contain multiple elements.

Comment: What is the problem you think you're solving by not using "new" when you want a new object? `$ex2 = (new Page)->add_content('example2');` is only a few extra characters, and has no hidden magic which will confuse everyone who reads the code. I also have no idea what you mean by "You can think of it like a pdo clas"

Comment: @Riga please update your question and provide some clarification, images, diagrams, or outputs, so I can help you, I have posted that answer based on your current question and output.

Answer (score -1):

I have solved your problem in this way, please let me know if I have misunderstood in any case so, I can fix it for you.

here is my example and I will explain how it works:

```
<?php

class Page
{
    public $contents = array();
    private $objectName = "";


    public function add_content($content)
    {
        array_push($this->contents,$content);
        return $this;
    }

    public function add_content2($content, Page $page){

        if ($this->objectName === $page->objectName){
            array_push($this->contents,$content);
        }else{
            $this->contents = null;
            $this->contents[] = $content;
        }

        return $this;
    }


    public function __construct($objectName)
    {
        $this->objectName = $objectName;
    }

}

$page = new Page("page1");
$page2 = new Page("page2");

// I want to add [example, example2] content to same page.
$ex = $page->add_content2('example', $page);
$ex = $page->add_content2('example2', $page);

// I want to add [example2] content to same page2.
$ex2 = $page2->add_content2('example2', $page2);

// I want to add [example2] content to same page2 via page
// this will reset the array and push the last
$ex3 = $page2->add_content2('example2', $page);


echo "<pre>Page 1: \n";
print_r($ex);
echo "</pre>";

echo "<pre>Page 2: \n";
print_r($ex2);
echo "</pre>";

echo "<pre>Page 3: \n";
print_r($ex3);
echo "</pre>";

?>
```

**My Solution, ** to keep track of which object has been called, I have created a variable so each page has a **unique name**, and then I will pass the object to the add_content method

```
private $objectName = "";
```

each object has to have Name passed to the **__construct**:

```
public function __construct($objectName)
{
    $this->objectName = $objectName;
}

$page = new Page("page1");
$page2 = new Page("page2");
```

**Now,** when I want to add new content to the page, we will check if it is the same in the **add_content2** method:

```
public function add_content2($content, Page $page){

    if ($this->objectName === $page->objectName){
        array_push($this->contents,$content);
    }else{
        $this->contents = null;
        $this->contents[] = $content;
    }

    return $this;
}
```

if it is the same, we can add it, if not we will reset the array **contents** and last we will add the content

please let me know if you don't understand.
here is my local result:

[image: My Result]
[image: For IMSop]

Comment: If you're willing to create two Page objects, why do you need to call `$ex2 = $page2->add_content2('example2', $page2);` rather than just `$ex2 = $page2->add_content('example2');`? Or since you want it to start empty, `$ex2 = (new Page)->add_content('example2');`

Comment: @IMSoP, I understand the **Riga** want he wants, as I told him before you really don't need this but the solution for him, is like mine, just send the **object** to the method. I just keep his method, so he can make difference between them, **if** you are talking about why I called 2 times, then I just wanted to show him he can add content unless he changes the page.

Comment: What I'm saying is that sending the object to the method makes no sense, because it's already there in the special variable `$this`. This doesn't actually do anything special to decide when to clear, you just manually force it by passing any unrelated object; it could be rewritten as `function add_content($content, bool $shouldClear)`

Comment: @IMSoP, if you read his question and his comments, you will understand the wants to use the same but in some way **prevent** calling the method from another object. 

you can't do that with **bool $shouldClear** because it is the **same** object, before this, I created that with **int contentCount**, after I read his comment I changed that to this, so he can use that. the idea here is **$this's the name** and **caller's name** must be the same and then add a new one, else must be clear and added. please give me a moment I will add an image

Comment: There is nothing "prevented" by this code, and nothing "being called from a different object". Every time you call `$page->add_content2`, you are choosing whether to clear it or not by passing one of two values - you've used $page and $page2, but they don't actually do anything other than trigger the if statement, so you might as well use true and false.

Comment: You also don't need the $objectName property, `if ( $this === $page )` would do just the same thing.

Comment: @IMSoP have you tried my code so far?
can you try adding content to page1 via page2?
just give me a sec, I will upload an image so you have a better understanding

Comment: let's move this to chat, shall we?
**if ( $this === $page )** will only be true when adding with the same object, if you try using a different one, this code doesn't let that happen.

Comment: Sorry, it's well past my bedtime. But there is no code here to do with "adding content to page1 via page2". The content is always added to the object you call the method on; there is just an extra parameter that can be used to clear the list. The fact that the extra parameter is another instance of the same class makes no difference to how it works, and the name property inside that object has even less purpose.

Comment: @IMSoP, please take a look at the diagram, I have uploaded, I told you, he want to **prevent** adding when someone called the same method with a **different variable** not the same, how you can keep track if it is the same object or not? that is the key, you pass the object to the method and there you can check if it is same or not. anytime you can let me know when you have time, so we can have a better understanding of each other.

Comment: @IMSoP, you can check it tomorrow, but here is a quick answer for **"But there is no code here to do with..."**
$page = new Page("page1");
$page2 = new Page("page2");
$ex3 = $page2->add_content2('example2', $page);

Comment: The same object as what? You're passing in a variable you know is a different object, so you know it's going to clear the list; you could use `$clearPlease = new Page('');` and pass that in - it doesn't have to do anything, or even be an object at all. As I commented under the question, it's completely unclear what the actual problem being solved is. If you want an empty object, create it; if you don't, don't.

Comment: As for the $objectName, try it without - PHP already knows which object is which, you don't have to give them names. The only reason to have names as well would be to have two with the *same* name, but you never do that in your example.

Comment: I have created 2 objects and my new method requires **content and object**, why do I have to send an object? well to check if it sends the same one or not. if he wants to clear the array content it is easy with the same object he created, created a method, and clear it. **But,** he don't want to clear content that way, **he wants the content to be cleared When same method called from somewhere else**

Comment: @IMSoP, as I mentioned before, I just wanted to solve his problem, and I have provided a simple and easy solution for him, I know each object is unique and you don't need to give the name, but I created that, so I can use it in my logic.
I am pretty sure there are so many ways to implement this, but the main point of his question I think is don't let objects to call that "shared" content array, and I really don't know how he wants that, if he gives more info, we can give him more and better solution.

Comment: @AwatITWork I think you misunderstood my question. Why would I need 2 different functions? The subject is very simple I guess, but I couldn't explain what I wanted. In short, I want the coding not to be long and to progress easily. After creating the class in the $page variable, if I call a method on any different variable, I want it to reset the $contents array. With the __call method, I think I can do this. But $page->add_content('example')->add_content('example_2'); In this type of usage, the array will be reset continuously since the method is called every time.

Comment: @Riga, I understand that and you only need one method, **add_content2($content, Page $page)**, I know what you want, you have that method and if you called that from any other object it should be clear the content for that object, try that code I have provided, also you can provide images if you can't explain it with words.

Comment: @AwatITWork I understand your system, but that's not what I want? Consider that there are hundreds of different pages, I don't want to create a class by typing new for each one. Also, reset if not empty doesn't make any sense. I don't think the add_content2 function is needed here. It's not something I can use in an immersive way, so the code you gave as an example. Have you had a chance to look at the __call magic method?

Comment: @Riga it is too late for me now, tomorrow I will check that too, but could you please update the question, do you want to ONLY one time to create an object and from that object act it as different pages!? I thought you want the way to know who is calling the add_Content method and preventing adding when the object is a new one, so the easy way is by assigning a key in my case name, and send the object to the method. I will check that for you too, but as I read your question and comments, that is the solution for the current question, if you can create an image showing a digram it will helps.